# Is it possible to edit "Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Policy Install" task through GPO?

Tags: windows, group-policy, scheduled-tasks, windows-10-v1809

I am curious if it is possible to modify this task through GPO or modify any tasks that are not in the root of the Task Scheduler Library.  The reason for this is that Microsoft somehow forgot to give this policy the option to "Run tasks as soon as possible after scheduled start is missed", which is causing issues with laptops that are not powered on during the Auto Update install time.  I have also seen laptops that were powered on and still did not run this task for some reason.  The inconsistencies with Windows Updates is killing me! lol.

I feel like if I can somehow tick this box this would solve a lot of my problems.  We have a very specific schedule to adhere to for installing updates, which needs to happen on the 4th Monday of the month and should (hopefully) be completed by Friday.  We want to avoid weekend installs, so I unfortunately cannot set this policy for "Everyday" on the "4th Week of the Month".

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make this task "policy install" as is is not present in my 1903 W10.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Moab.  It looks like this task gets created when you use the Windows Update policy "Configure Automatic Updates".  Here is the weird thing, it doesn't create this task on all computers.  We have 1809 and my laptop is on 1903.  I received this task and then it seems like about a 50/50 split on systems that get this task and those that don't.

Answer (score 1):

Woohoo, success!  So I initially tried creating a scheduled task with the same folder path and name and used this:

\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Policy Install

Come to find out, I needed to omit the preceding "\"

Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Policy Install

I then used similar settings as the one the Windows Update GPO created, but I ticked the box to "Run the task..." instead.  On my test machine that was pending an update I did a gpupdate and noticed that the Windows Update GPO created task was updated with the box ticked.  The nice thing is that I now get all the granularity for days, weeks, times, etc.

I also ran a quick test to see if this task would in fact run if it was missed, and it worked!  Still not sure why the actual GPO does not give you this sort of flexibility.  I think these settings will help a lot of folks that have struggled endlessly with the mysterious Windows 10 update system.

Hopefully this will help someone out there that has been banging their head with this like I have.